# Why does CDF tend to be a power-law around 0?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, soft-question, asymptotics

If we look at CDF of various famous random variables around 0, they tend to be well approximated by a power law. Why?

Below are 24 examples, notable exceptions are log-normal, Frechet, Inverse Gamma and Inverse Normal, the rest appear to be fit with a power law.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{ChiSquared} & \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \sqrt{x} \\
 \text{Marchenko-Pastur} & \frac{2 \sqrt{x}}{\pi } \\
 \text{Beta(1/2,1)} & \sqrt{x} \\
 \text{ArcSin} & \frac{2 \sqrt{x}}{\pi } \\
 \text{Weihbul(1/2,2)} & \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 \text{Exponential} & x \\
 \text{Chi} & \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} x \\
 \text{Student-T} & \frac{2 x}{\pi } \\
 \text{Normal} & \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} x \\
 \text{Cauchy} & \frac{2 x}{\pi } \\
 \text{Semicircle} & \frac{2 x}{\pi } \\
 \text{Gumbel} & x \\
 \text{F-ratio(2,2)} & x \\
 \text{Gamma(1,2)} & \frac{x}{2} \\
 \text{Extreme Value} & \frac{x}{e-1} \\
 \text{Logistic} & \frac{x}{2} \\
 \text{Uniform} & x \\
 \text{Inverse Normal} & -\frac{e x^2}{16}-\frac{x^2}{16}+\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} e^{-\frac{(x-2)^2}{8 x}} \sqrt{x} \\
 \text{Erlang(2,2)} & 2 x^2 \\
 \text{Triangle} & 2 x^2 \\
 \text{Kumaraswamy(2,3)} & 3 x^2 \\
 \text{Bates(3)} & \frac{9 x^3}{2} \\
 \text{LogNormal} & -\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} \log ^2(x)}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \log (x)} \\
 \text{InverseGamma} & e^{-2/x} \\
 \text{Frechet(2,1,0)} & e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} \\
 \text{Pareto(1,2)} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-distribution-growth.nb)

Comment: I do not see Bernoulli, Geometric, Poisson on your list. I do not know what those expressions in your chart mean. I think those expressions on your chart are approximations of $P[|X|\leq x]$ for positive $x\approx 0$. Then, any continuous random variable with a PDF that is continuous at $0$ and satisfies $f_X(0)\neq 0$ would have $P[|X|\leq x] \approx 2f_X(0)x$ for positive $x\approx 0$. If the PDF has support only for $x\geq 0$ and is right-continuous at $x=0$ with $f_X(0)\neq 0$, such as uniform or exponential, then we get $P[|X|\leq x]=P[X\in [0,x]]\approx f_X(0)x$ for $x\approx 0$.

Comment: @Michael the table gives asymptotic expansion of CDF (Mathematica's `Asymptotic`function) around 0 for continuous random variables truncated to positive values. So normal distribution was truncated to discard negatives. Most of the named distributions produce CDF that is $O(x^p)$ around 0. Exceptions are LogNormal, Frechet, Inverse Normal and Inverse Gamma, was wondering what makes those distributions special

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting your chart. For $X\sim N(0,1)$ and positive $x\approx 0$ we have $P[X \in [0,x]] \approx \frac{x}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ and $P[|X|\leq x] \approx \left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\right)x$, and the latter is what is given in your chart (the chart is not truncating to discard negatives).

Comment: In general, if $X$ has a PDF that is continuous over some interval $[0, \delta]$, then for $c>0$, you can use L'Hopital's rule to calculate $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{P[X \in [0,x]]}{x^c} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\int_0^x f_X(t)dt}{x^c}= \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f_X(x)}{cx^{c-1}}$$ assuming the final limit exists. The unusual cases are when $f_X(x)\rightarrow 0$ very rapidly as $x\rightarrow 0^+$ (faster than a power law).

Comment: @Michael yes, misspecified how "truncation" was done. Random variable is renormalized after discarding negatives, so it's equivalent to considering $P(|X|<x)$ when $X$ is symmetric

Comment: @Michael interesting. So L'Hopital trick implies you get $O(x)$ power law whenever pdf of $X$ converges to c>0 at x=0. Then we continue to get power laws when we take powers or add up IID  copies of such variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This summarizes my comments with some more detail:

Suppose $X$ has a continuous CDF and has a PDF that is continuous over some interval $(0,\delta)$ (for some $\delta>0$). Then for any $c>0$ we have by L'Hopital's rule together with the fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{P[X \in [0, x]]}{x^c} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\int_0^x f_X(t)dt}{x^c} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f_X(x)}{cx^{c-1}}$$
assuming the final limit exists.

For example:

- Exponential:  $f_X(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x} 1_{\{x\geq 0\}}$
  $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{P[X \in [0,x]]}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f_X(x)}{1} = \lambda$$
- Erlang: $f_X(x) = x\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda x} 1_{\{x\geq 0\}}$
  $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{P[X \in [0,x]]}{x^2} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f_X(x)}{2x} = \frac{\lambda^2}{2}$$
- Normal: $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)}$
  $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{P[X \in [0,x]]}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f_X(x)}{1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}$$
- Chi squared: $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}e^{-x/2}1_{\{x\geq 0\}}$
  $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{P[X \in [0,x]]}{x^{1/2}} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f_X(x)}{(1/2)x^{-1/2}} = \sqrt{2/\pi}$$

The unusual cases are when $f_X(x)\rightarrow 0$ very rapidly as $x\rightarrow 0^+$, faster than a power law $x^c$ for any $c>0$ (such as the $e^{-\beta/x}$ behavior of an inverse gamma with parameter $\beta>0$).

---

Note that your chart seems to be giving functions $g(x)$ such that
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{P[|X|\leq x]}{g(x)}=1$$

- When $X$ is a nonnegative random variable then
  $$P[|X|\leq x]=P[X \in [0,x]] \quad \forall x>0$$
- When $X$ has a PDF that is symmetric about 0 then $$P[|X|\leq x]=2P[X\in [0,x]] \quad \forall x>0$$

Comment: Thanks for in-depth reply. It appears that behavior of CDF of singular values of random matrix is much [more constained](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4737370/singular-values-of-random-matrix-with-iid-entries)