# Singular values of random matrix with IID entries

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

Chart below is log-log plot of empirical CDF of the distribution of singular values for a  matrix with IID random entries.

It tends to $O(x)$ for small $x$ regardless of the distribution, why?

[image]

Meanwhile CDF of absolute values of eigenvalues appears to be $O(x^2)$

[image]

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-eigenvalue-distributions.nb)

Comment: In general, log-log plots tend to make things look more linear

Comment: @User5678 that's true, but it's not obvious to me why all the plots are consistently $O(x)$. Having $O(x^2)$ behavior would also appear linear, added some more plots

Comment: so you're saying here that the distribution of the singular values themselves have this log-linear behavior and eigenvalue magnitudes are log-quadratic.

Do these CDFs represent a single set of singular/eigenvalues per distribution or are you creating CDF from multiple repetitions of each matrix?

I ask b/c its not clear that random square matrices will have the same number of eigenvalues each time and the singular values or eigenvalues of a matrix likely have some internal correlation structure.

Why not plot $\max \sigma(A)$ and $\max |\lambda(A)|$? that may be an easier place to start

Comment: @User5678 it's a single $n\times n$ matrix, although for large $n$ it doesn't matter, eigenvalue density of a single matrix approaches limiting spectral density ([notes](https://random-matrix-learning.github.io/#presentation1)). For Gaussian matrices results are well-known, whereas this plot shows that there's this rule of thumb extends beyond Gaussian matrices